# Is using protocol and delegate to create a Control like UITableView the optimized one?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, protocols

The UITableView can be used to create a list view if the at least the UITableViewDataSource is adopted by the relevant class. I have the below questions:

Why is it designed in such a way that based on the section and row , the controls are created through data source methods and given back  to the UITableView instance. Why not provide all these information in UITableView instance with out using the UITableViewDataSource. What difference is it going to make?

**EDIT1:**
@hermann and @JOhn: You have mentioned that it breaks the MVC pattern. Let us assume I am creating a custom UITableView like control myself. I design it in such a way that I do not pass the data directly to the UITableView but instead I pass the relevant subviews that needs to be added in the rows and section and their relavant headers alone. I think this will not break the MVC..Am I correct? But still it has the problem that the current UITableView implementation style solves..the ability to reuse controls and images instead of bloating the memory usage.

Comment: Keeping the data information in the UITableView instance negates the MVC pattern..

Comment: Thanks David.Can you answer the updated question..

Comment: It seems like your custom tableView is very similar to UITableView, where UITableView has a datasource which hands it UITableViewCells and UIViews for the table section headers. what exactly are you suggesting? because i can't understand what will be different in your case..

Comment: I just want to clear something that i don't think you fully understood, a UITableView has a datasource (mostly a UIViewController subclass) which hands the view cells for rows and views for sections. the controller does not hand the view the data. it is in charge of setting the data in the view. in our case it does it by implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol..

Comment: Thanks David Ben Ari..You cleared my doubt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, doing so allows to stick on the MVC pattern. A UI object, meaning a view, should never directly communitcate with the model, wich is the business data. Plus it should not perform any business logic, which belongs to the controller.

Second, it is more flexible without the need of subclassing the UITableView object.

Third, the full concept is quite efficient from a performance and memory management point of view. Instead of loading all data upfront, that may be displied within a table, it can be fetched or calculated or whatever on a just in time "need to know now" basis.
Plus data containers, especially memory consuming once like images, can be released as soon as the data has been provided using the delegate/data source methods.

Of course, a subclass of UITableView could do the same in principle. I just doubt this would result in more maintainable code or even save any time or work resprectively.

If you don't want to stick with MVC, then feel free to subclassing the table view and hand all its data over in its init method or enable the table view subclass to load all that data from webservices or data bases or wherever it comes from. 
And when you run into problems and get back to us searching for guidance, then be prepared for some nasty replies like "Why don't you stick to the established best practices or the MVC pattern?" ect.

In the event that your very table just displays some rather static values, such as if it just acts as menu for further navigation drill down etc. then this concept may look a bit rediculous. But it does not hurt either. And when it comes to more complex tasks of data providing then it certainly has its advantages.

Give it a chance. Give it a try!

Comment: Can you explain in detail about the second point you are making..I guess this will not apply to a Custom Control (not related to any built in controls like TableView) I might create.Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the delegate is no substitute for custom controls. If you want to change the appearance of a table view then subclassing it might be appropriate. Well, at least if you aim to do changes that you cannot influence enough by using delegate methods like viewForHeaderInSection etc. Without a delegate you would have to subclass each table. Thanks to the delegate (and data source) pattern you can do all the business logic in the controller - to where it belongs.

Comment: I think that MVC pattern also cannot absolutely make the controller not at all being in involved in view related work as still when we set the delegate of the UITableView as self(her the controller) we do let the controller create the views for headers and footers and the cell creation also..So I think we can not be exactly following MVC but the degree of the compliance to MVC is higher..

Answer (score 1):

For MVC you want to try to clearly separate what the model, controller, and views are responsible for doing.  By allowing the view (tableview) to ask for the data from a delegate, the view can be create extremely generalized.

Using the delegate pattern, the controller can "stage" the data in anyway that is wants and then give it to tableView as the tableView needs it.  The tableView doesn't care where the data comes, how it was transformed, what ADT is used, nothing.  It is complete ignorant to where or what the data is.  All it knows it should show this string at this location for this section and row.